# Pimcore - Impossible to save an object

Tags: php, symfony, pimcore

[Pimcore 10 - PHP 8 - Symfony 5]

I try to update a gallery with new asset(s). All seems to work fine until I try to save my object :

`Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Data\Hotspotimage::getImage(): Return value must be of type ?Pimcore\Model\Asset\Image, Pimcore\Model\Asset returned`

Here is the part of my script I have a problem with :

```
$asset = new Asset();
$asset->setFilename($filename);
$asset->setData(file_get_contents($somewhere . '/' . $filename));
$asset->setParent(Asset::getByPath('/folder/' . $sub_folder . '/'));
$asset->save();

$galleryAssets = $object->getMyGallery();
$currentItems = array_filter($galleryAssets->getItems());

$advancedImage = new \Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Data\Hotspotimage();
$advancedImage->setImage($asset);
$currentItems[] = $advancedImage;

$object->setMyGallery(new \Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Data\ImageGallery($currentItems));
$object->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having more context I assume you need to create an instance of `Pimcore\Model\Asset\Image` on line 1 of your example, instead of the type `Pimcore\Model\Asset`. The error implies that you're trying to add an image of the wrong class type via `Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Data\Hotspotimage::setImage()`

Comment: In fact I think my problem is :
"How to put an asset in a hotspot ?"
or
"How to transform an asset into image?"

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the Image by

```
$img = Asset\Image::getById($asset->getId());
```

And add this image to your hotspotimage

```
$advancedImage->setImage($asset);
```

I know it's not optimal because it requires additional resources. But I don't know how else the asset class can be cast as a subclass.